# How to find the longest consecutive digits

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to find the longest consecutive digits from a string of digits. For example, given:

```
"12233344445"
```

I expect to return:

```
"4444"
```

I can find that using iteration, but I think that using regex would be cool although it's not efficient. It should be simple but I can't do it. Please enlighten me. I use Ruby, but any language will do.

Comment: Regex can't decipher length. Or, do length comparisons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Longest recurring cycle of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30289341/longest-recurring-cycle-of-digits)

Comment: @Martin, this problem is to find the longest substring in a string of digits of the form `d*n`, where `d` is one of the 10 digits (e.g., '4'*5 #=> "44444"`), whereas the problem you referenced concerns infinitely repeating digits in the decimal representation of a rational number.

Comment: Nuckle dragger method: `s.scan(/1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+|0+/).max_by(&:length)`

Comment: What if there's a tie?

Answer (score 5):

Regardless of the regular expression you use, subsequent iteration will be required. Here's one way.

```
str = "12233344445"

str.gsub(/(\d)\1*/).max_by(&:size)
  #=> "4444"
```

We have

```
enum = str.gsub(/(\d)\1*/)
  #=> #<Enumerator: "12233344445":gsub(/(\d)\1*/)>
```

We can convert this to an array to see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator.

```
enum.to_a
  #=> ["1", "22", "333", "4444", "5"]
```

The regular expression reads, "Match a digit in capture group 1, followed by zero or more characters that equal the contents of capture group 1."

This uses the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) where no block is given. (Here the method has nothing to do with character substitution, which can be a bit confusing.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a scanner to find all matches then flatten to find the longest match:

```
> "12233344445".scan(/((\d)\2*)/).flatten.max_by(&:length)
=> "4444"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is convert the string to an array and use **Enuberable** [chunk_while](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) on it:

```
num.each_char.chunk_while {|i, j| j == i }.to_a
#=> [["1"], ["2", "2"], ["3", "3", "3"], ["4", "4", "4", "4"], ["5"]]
```

So you can get for example:

```
num.each_char.chunk_while {|i, j| j == i }.map(&:join) #=> ["1", "22", "333", "4444", "5"]
```

Or just get the longest string, for example in this way:

```
num.each_char.chunk_while {|i, j| j == i }.max_by(&:length).join() #=> "4444"
```

Comment: You can use`each_char` instead of `split`.